# Send prop to ReactJs from Express response (render)

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, passport.js, flux

I have a simple application with [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js), [express](/questions/tagged/express), [passport](/questions/tagged/passport) and [react-js](/questions/tagged/react-js).

I have an `index.html` who includes `client.js` that is a simple render of [react-js](/questions/tagged/react-js):

```
var React = require('react');
var React = require('react-dom');
var Client = require('./Client.jsx');
ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(Client, null),
    document.getElementById('main')
);
```

`Client` is the real Application.

On the server side (`routes.js`) I have this:
    app.get('/login', function(req, res){
        res.render('login');
    });

```
app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }),function(req, res){});
app.get('/auth/google/callback',passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.get('/', ensureAuthenticated ,function(req, res){
    req.session.id = req.user._id; //From MongoDb
    res.render('index', { user: req.user });
});

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) { return next(); }
    res.redirect('/login')
}
```

I want to send some information from the loged user (username, real name, avatar, and others) to the top hierarchy [react-js](/questions/tagged/react-js) component.

- The way to go is use cookies?
- Using [express-session](/questions/tagged/express-session) is like use cookies right?
- Can I update flux ([reflux.js](/questions/tagged/reflux.js)) store with express on the response?
- Is there any way to send props to the top reactjs component (`Client`)?
  I don't like to handle cookies but if there is no other way to do this I will use cookies.

Comment: The normal way is to JSON.stringify the data in the html template in a script tag, and then parse it out on the client with JSON.parse. You can hydrate a flux store with that, you can also wrap your app in a component which declares the data as context accessible to any component (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html). You can see an example here https://github.com/DominicTobias/universal-react/. Note - some flux packages like Alt and Redux help you with this process.

Comment: @DominicTobias thanks, I'm reading your links.